# Escaping Backslash using Knex.raw for \Copy command in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, knex.js

We were trying to use the \COPY command in Knex.raw. We connect via heroku/postgres and the \COPY is the only way to bulk import data as we don't have superuser rights. The backslash before the copy is being removed or multiplied depending on what you try.

So far we've tried to escape it using 
1. \b
2. \
3. String.fromCharCode(92)
4. concatenation

The full function we're using is...

```
knex.raw("\COPY tablename (column1, column2, ...columnN) FROM STDIN " + csvValues).then(function(response){
console.log('the response from the copy', response);
```

});

We've tested this exact function within our pg:psql environment and it works perfectly. If you know of a better way of doing this, please let us know!

Regards,
Brandon

Comment: khampson is right `\copy` is not a SQL command. I don't know knex, but maybe you could use `copy .. from stdin` and the send the data through a stream (the JDBC driver has a special class to support this). No idea if this is possible with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\copy` is a [*psql*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) (client) command, which wraps *Postgres*'s [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) (server). It sounds like perhaps you're trying to combine the two, and that's where the problem is.

Since *knex.js* is a query builder, it wouldn't know about `\copy` -- `\COPY` would not be valid *SQL* to use in a client scenario.

You mention that you don't have *superuser* access, which, if you want to reference a file, is required for `COPY`.

If you're unable to use `COPY` for that reason, you would instead need to use *psql* and leverage its `\copy` command, for which *knex.js* would likely not be the tool to use. Rather, you would need to access it via the invocation of a shell command.

Perhaps this batch import of data could be done outside of *Javascript* entirely? i.e. via a *bash* script that used *psql* directly?

Comment: Khampson, thanks for the response. From what I understood of the problem, I think Knex isn't escaping certain values properly -- specifically when a double slash is used. We brought it up with Knex who gave us this workaround https://www.npmjs.org/package/pg-copy-streams. This worked like a charm to bulk import our data.

Comment: Ah, sounds like *pg-copy-streams* is essentially a wrapper for the psql `\copy` command.